# Linux kernel IPv6 route lookup - how does it work?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, routing

I am testing forwarding speed in the linux kernel with source address constrained routes. Meaning a route entry is matched only if both the destination and the source address of a packet match.

For simplicity, I would like to have all routes use the same outgoing interface. Now I am wondering if doing this might lead to some kind of shortcut in the lookup algorithm. Maybe it won't search through everything, like it would if each route used a different outgoing interface?

Will this be a problem? How is the route lookup implemented?